How can i drag all scene in godot engine 3.5.3
I have scene with Paddle, which contains sprite and collisionshape, i need to hold finger on paddle and drag it on y axis in mobile app, what should i do so?
extends KinematicBody2D

var is_dragging = false
var touchpose = Vector2()

var min_y = 63
var max_y = 511

onready var paddle_sprite = $Paddle1

func _ready():
    if paddle_sprite == null:
        print("Error: Paddle sprite not found!")
        return

func _input(event):
    if paddle_sprite == null:
        return

    if event is InputEventScreenTouch or event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.is_pressed():
            if paddle_sprite.get_rect().has_point(event.position):
                is_dragging = true
                touchpose = event.position
        else:
            is_dragging = false

    elif event is InputEventScreenDrag or event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        if is_dragging:
            touchpose = event.position

func _physics_process(delta):
    if is_dragging and paddle_sprite != null:
        var new_position = global_position
        new_position.y = clamp(touchpose.y, min_y, max_y)
        global_position = new_position


I dont need x axis motion, i need to hold touch on texture of paddle and drag it
